# Apostrophe-cms not displaying widgets when using bootstrap

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am using apostrophecms with bootstrap.I have referred the below github example 
https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe-gallery-demo

It is creating the webpage correctly , the problem is that it is not displaying the widgets.
my layout.html file: which displays contents correctly

```
{# Automatically extends the right outer layout and also handles AJAX siutations #}
{% extends data.outerLayout %}

{% block title %}
{# Create a useful, SEO-friendly title tag based on what we have #}
{% if data.piece %}
{{ data.piece.title }}
{% elseif data.page %}
{{ data.page.title }}
{% else %}
{{ apos.log(‘Looks like you forgot to override the title block in a template that does not have access to an Apostrophe page or piece.’) }}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extraHead %}
{#
This block outputs its contents in the HTML document’s .
It is a good place to put extra and tags.
#}
{% endblock %}

{% block beforeMain %}

FAQ
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
{#
Usually, your page templates in the apostrophe-pages module will override
this block. It is safe to assume this is where your page-specific content
should go.
#}
{% endblock %}

{% block afterMain %}

 Logo
{% endblock %}
my default page template used:

{% extends “layout.html” %}

{% import “macros/utils.html” as utils with context %}

{% block main %}

{{ utils.columns() }} {% endblock %}
```

Please help on how my widgets will get visible on the page.
PS: I am a beginner in apostrophecms

Comment: Hi Rem, can you clarify what you mean by "not displaying the widgets?" When you log in, do you not see any buttons for adding widgets?

Comment: Thanks for the response.I figured out the issue. I was using a different page template.

Comment: I have one question though.I want to use a card with header and body as a widget.do you have any examples on how to use it.
[with bootstrap or without bootstrap will be good] It would be great for a reference.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sure, in `widget.html` you can output those fields, or nest additional `apos.singleton` and `apos.area` calls passing `data.widget` as if it were a page.

Comment: Here's an example to get you started on a card widget:
https://codepen.io/zindarato/pen/MZybde

You'll want to change the styles to make your card look however you want. Then, you'll be able to add a card widget on any pages where you have an area that's allowed to add a widget of that type.

Comment: I got this error:
'Uncaught The type card-widget-widgets-editor is not defined.'

Comment: There is utils.html below.do I need to change this: https://codepen.io/remyap19/pen/gZMgzN